# Audit Trail Design in Hibernate using Interceptors

Tags: hibernate, interceptor, audit-logging

I am new to Hibernate and wants to maintain the Audit Information across most of the tables (but not for all). Here is the work done.

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;
@Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "LASTNAME")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;
@Column(name = "PHONE")
private String phone;
@Embedded
AuditInformation auditInformation;
```

**AuditInformation.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class AuditInformation implements Auditable {

    @Column(name = "Created_Date")
    private Date createdDt;
    @Column(name = "Created_By")
    private String createdBy;
    @Column(name = "Last_modified_by")
    private String lastModifiedBy;
    @Column(name = "last_modified_Date")
    private Date lastModifiedDt;
```

**Auditable.java**

```
public interface Auditable {
    public void setCreatedDt(Date createdDt);    
    public Date getCreatedDt();    
    public void setLastModifiedDt(Date createdDt);
    public Date getLastModifiedDt();
}
```

**AuditInfoInterceptor.java**

```
public class AuditInfoInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(final Object entity, final Serializable id,
            final Object[] currentState, final Object[] previousState,
            final String[] propertyNames, final Type[] types) {

        if (entity instanceof Auditable) {
            for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
                if (propertyNames[i] == "createdDt") {
                    currentState[i] = new java.util.Date();
                    return true;
                }
                if (propertyNames[i] == "lastModifiedDt") {
                    currentState[i] = new java.util.Date();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(final Object entity, final Serializable id,
            final Object[] state, final String[] propertyNames,
            final Type[] types) {
        if (entity instanceof Auditable) {
            for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
                if (propertyNames[i] == "createdDt") {
                    state[i] = new java.util.Date();
                    return true;
                }
                if (propertyNames[i] == "lastModifiedDt") {
                    state[i] = new java.util.Date();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;    
    }
}
```

**spring-context.xml**

```
<bean id="hibernate4AnnotationSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>Employee</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor" />
```

Now I wanted to store the audit information to database which I am able to store after populating the object with `save()` method. But my interceptor is not doing any update as it fails with `instanceof` check and does nothing. Now my questions around this are

- How come the `lastModifiedDt` property/Object would be available to my Interceptor as it only looks for Entity (which is `Employee` in my case)?

Please suggest if it is the correct design. As I am in the learning phase. Hence, trying to do in this manner. I will look for [Hibernate Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) after this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`lastModifiedDt` is there because you embedded `AuditInformation` as `Employee`'s property. It then becomes part of the `state` of the entity and `propertyNames`.